# SFTP batch transfer without passphrase

Tags: shell, automation, sftp

I am trying to send a bunch of files to a server using SFTP with public key auth. How can I do that without the shell prompting for the passphrase?

My script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
do
  sftp USER@HOST << DELIMITER
   cd DIR
   put $f
   quit
DELIMITER

done
```

Comment: This question is not linked to [tag:batch-file] (DOS/Windows batch scripts), so please correct the tags!

Comment: Corrected. Sorry I have mistaken batch-file for "batch" file processing

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh-agent`:

```
#!/bin/bash
eval `ssh-agent`
ssh-add /path/to/your/key

for f in "$@"
do
  sftp USER@HOST << DELIMITER
   cd DIR
   put $f
   quit
DELIMITER

done
```

It will store your key in `ssh-agent`, asks for passphrase once and then logs you in to all servers. You can do that also outside of the script.

Comment: The script is meant to be "automatically" executed through cron jobs. Would it be possible to add a passphrase once before setting up the whole process?

Comment: Yes. You can start the agent manually and then set appropriate variable `$SSH_AUTH_SOCK` to the script, if it will run under the same user. Check manual page for `ssh-add`